# How to implement IStringLocalizer interface to use database source instead of .resx in Blazor localization?

Tags: database, interface, localization, blazor, resources

I want to implement database source as the resource for localization instead of .resx files. Currently I'm saving my translation key, value pairs in a Azure blob. There are blobs for each and every language. So, I want to use that blob as my resource instead of .resx files. I've a a service to retrieve blobs.

Documentation specified,

> ASP.NET Core localization provides ResourceManagerStringLocalizer.
> ResourceManagerStringLocalizer is an implementation of
> IStringLocalizer that uses resx to store localization resources.
>
> You aren't limited to using resx files. By implementing
> IStringLocalizer, any data source can be used.

I'm struggling with implementing IStringLocalizer interface to use blob data source. How can I implement that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It should be straightforward:

```
class MyLocalizer : IStringLocalizer 
{ 
}
```

VS will offer to add the required methods.
And in Program.cs add

```
services.AddTransient<IStringLocalizer, MyLocalizer>();
```

In Blazor Wasm that could be AddSingleton, I don't know how you would want to store the Blobs  server side.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the answer. But there is ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory implemented using IStringLocalizerFactory and which has Create method that creates _localizer and returns it. And my blob actually contains a dictionary(Key and Translation value). How can I set that dictionary to _localizer?